# Написание универсального простого кода сравнения Switch js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

я новичок в JavaScript, вопрос на засыпку, помогите красиво переписать , структурировать код.

у меня есть масив обьектов,

```
var array = [
{id:1,
Укрепление дверей: "Не укреплены"
Укрепление окон: "Не все укреплены"
Укрепление стен/крыши: "Укреплены"}
];
```

я итерирую масив, на каждой итерацию выполняю функцию колбэк, для каждого элемента масива,

```
  //block --текущий обьект с которым я работаю
  //у меня есть блок кода который выполнится если в свойствах обьекта,есть значения  
  //"Не укреплены" или "Не все укреплены"
  //суть вопроса в выражении, хочу сделать его универсальным ,но моих знаний не достаточно

angular.forEach(array, function (block) {
  switch(block['Укрепление дверей']){
     case "Не укреплены":
     case "Не все укреплены":
        console.log('блок кода');
        break;
  }
   if(block['Укрепление окон'] === "Не укреплены")
      console.log('блок кода');
   if(block['Укрепление стен/крыши'] === "Не укреплены")
      console.log('блок кода');
})
```

блок кода один и тот же, свойства обьекта разные ,я не знаю как написать универсальное выражение для проверки чтоб не дублировать код  console.log('блок кода');

думал написать как то так ,

```
   switch(block[имя свойства обьекта]){
     //проверяю если хоть 1 значение свойства === case:
    //выполняю код console.log('блок кода');
     case "Не укреплены":
     case "Не все укреплены":
        console.log('блок кода');
        break;
  }
```

спасибо за любые советы ! Задумка на универсальность, обьтектов в масиве может быть несколько.

Comment: `block['Укрепление окон'] === "Не укреплены") || block['Укрепление стен/крыши'] === "Не укреплены"`

Comment: А если свойств может быть любое количество, то в цикле перебирать все свойства объекта и проверять

Comment: @Laukhin Andrey , да этот вариант тоже смотрел, мне просто не нравится грамосткий код, проверка 3 условий каждого обьекта отдельно, через логическое или,  через if, будет работать, но мне такой подход кажется скучным ,  свойств постоянно 4 , ключ статический ,  могут принимать разные значения, вы хотите сказать перебирать обьект например циклом for in и проверять равно ли каждое свойство строке???

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите универсальный вариант, то предлагаю ввести массив "стоп-слов", тогда решение получается очень простым:

```js
var array = [{
  id: 1,
  "Укрепление дверей": "Не укреплены",
  "Укрепление окон": "Не все укреплены",
  "Укрепление стен/крыши": "Укреплены"
}];

let targetWords = ["Не укреплены", "Не все укреплены"];

array.forEach((obj) => {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (targetWords.indexOf(obj[key]) != -1)
      console.log(key);
  }
});
```

Comment: отлично! это как раз примерно , то что я хотел, дальше доработаю сам, спасибо большое ! отличная идея)